# how to apply CSS styles to oj-table in oracle JET?

Tags: css, oracle-jet

i have oracle jet  table like that

```
<oj-table  class='oj-table-data-cell-padding' id="table" aria-label="Departments Table"
                                data='[[dataSource]]'
                                display = "grid"
                                on-oj-before-current-row = "[[currentRowListener]]"
                                selectionMode = "{'row': 'single'}"
                                columns-default='{"sortable": "enabled"}'
                                dnd='{"reorder": {"columns": "enabled"}}'
                                style="width:100%;margin-bottom:40px; background-color: #1E90FF;"
                                columns='[{"headerText": "Course Id", 
                                                   "field": "Id",
                                                   "headerClassName": "oj-sm-only-hide",
                                                   "className": "oj-sm-only-hide",
                                                   "resizable": "enabled"},
                                                   {"headerText": "Course Name", 
                                                   "field": "CourseName",
                                                   "resizable": "enabled"},
                                                  {"headerText": "Description", 
                                                   "field": "CourseDescription",
                                                   "resizable": "enabled"},
                                                  {"headerText": "other Details", 
                                                   "field": "OtherDetail",
                                                   "headerClassName": "oj-sm-only-hide",
                                                   "className": "oj-sm-only-hide",
                                                   "resizable": "enabled"}

                                                    ]'

    </oj-table>
```

the problem is when i apply css , some of tags works and some are not
for example the background-color didn't work

so how to add CSS styles in oracle jet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. The reason `background-color` didn't work is because the OJET developers wanted us to be able to change only basic stuff like the height and width of components.

If you want to change anything more than that, like the aesthetics of the components, you have to use their [Theme Builder](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/public_samples/JET-Theme-Builder/public_html/index.html).

As a workaround, you could also inspect the elements and find the classes they use internally for a component and modify their values. For example,

```
.oj-table-element {
     background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how tooltip can be added to the oj-table header

```json
  columns='[{"headerText": "Course Id", 
 "field": "Id",
 "headerClassName": "oj-sm-only-hide",
"className": "oj-sm-only-hide",
"resizable": "enabled"},
{"headerText": "Course Name", 
"field": "CourseName",
"resizable": "enabled"},
{"headerText": "Description", 
"field": "CourseDescription",
"resizable": "enabled"},
"headerText": "other Details", 
"field": "OtherDetail",
"headerClassName": "oj-sm-only-hide",
"className": "oj-sm-only-hide",
"resizable": "enabled"}

                                                    ]
```

Comment: The question asked how to apply CSS on `oj-table` to modify the background colour. Not sure why you're talking about adding a tooltip.